# Python - Constantly monitor RSS feed (feedparser)

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I'm trying to figure out how to 'subscribe', or constantly monitor an RSS feed (Python 2.7, using feedparser).

The website I'm looking at is [DTCC](https://rtdata.dtcc.com/gtr/rssaction.do), at the "RSS Feed for Credits".

When you download the rss file, I can use feedparser to parse that, see the information contained inside etc, and thats all great.  But, because the file downloads locally, it obviously doesnt constantly update with new information.  My goal is to parse each rss reed as it comes in - and to build the event handler such that the parser kicks off when a new feed is released / new data does come in.

The rss file itself is stored [here](https://kgc0418-tdw-data-0.s3.amazonaws.com/slices/CREDITS_RSS_FEED.rss) if it helps.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: RSS feed do not push to the clients. Clients have to request them periodically.

Comment: Got you - that helps. So basically query every second for a newly released feed - if its the same as last throw out otherwise consume?

Comment: I asked a similar question over six years ago, never followed up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382942/reading-rss-feeds-what-aggregators-do-that-im-not.

Comment: You should expect getting blocked when you request the feed every second. Use a responsable time interval!

Comment: haha, fair.  Lets say I query every 10min, but they released 5 packets within that 10min.  How can you ensure that you get all those releases?